# Connect browser to NodeJS IPFS node

Tags: node.js, websocket, ipfs, libp2p, js-ipfs

I'm trying to connect a browser `js-ipfs` node to a my NodeJS server that is running an `js-ipfs` node as well. I understand that I need to add in the server's `Multiaddr` to the browser's bootstrap config in order to connect the two nodes.

However, since my website uses `HTTPS`, when I try to connect the browser to my server via `ws` it gives this warning: `An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.` but from my understanding NodeJS's `js-ipfs` cannot listen to `wss` calls.

So how can I go about connecting the two nodes? Is using WebSockets the only or best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to browser’s security policies you cannot establish unencrypted connection from secure context (e.g. page loaded via HTTPS). You can read about it at [MDN Secure Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts). So you should make your server to use SSL and then replace ws:// with wss://. The simplest thing to do would be to setup SSL with nginx. You’ll need to setup a domain name for the cert too.
You can also look on some documentation on how to setup libp2p/IPFS with SSL on this [PR](https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p/pull/718).

You can also use `webrtc-star` instead of websockets. However, while you can use both, each one of them have particularities that are better for certain scenarios.  If you need peer discovery, `webrtc-star` should be used at the moment and you can check https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p/tree/master/examples/libp2p-in-the-browser and https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/tree/master/examples/browser-exchange-files . If you do not need to rely on peer discovery and the other peer is a well known peer you can use bootstrap and connect via websockets.